# Node.js child process spawn isn't returning stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I've been trying to solve this issue for a few days with absolutely no luck. I have a node.js application that is spawning a child process - it's looking at the STDOUT of that child process and reacting to it. A snippet looks like:

```
    var childProc = spawn('/opt/Game/LaunchGame.sh');
    childProc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("stdout: " + data);
    });
    childProc.on('close', function(code){
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
```

If I run the bash script by itself, all the log messages appear as I'd expect, but when its run through Node, I never see any "stdout: " messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: The script is writing to `stderr` instead?

Comment: what happens for this: `spawn('/opt/Game/LaunchGame.sh', [], {stdio: "inherit"})` ?